# Why can't I edit the sudoers.d files with vim but I can with nano

Tags: vim, vagrant, vi

I tried editing a file in the `sudoers.d` directory using `vi` in a vagrant box **(Ubuntu Trusty64)** but it just opens the file in **readonly** mode but when I use the `nano` editor it works.

The command `sudo vi /etc/sudoers.d/student` only opens the file in readonly mode and any edits done are lost on save but to edit this same file the command `sudo nano /etc/sudoers.d/student` works. Also note `sudo visudo ...` works.

They appears to be some restrictions in using `vi` on such file which I want to know.

My current system is Ubuntu Focal Fossa.

Comment: It does not returns the error "readonly"

Comment: Related: you should probably use the `visudo` tool to not lock yourself out accidentally.

Comment: @peregrino69 I have update my question I hope it's clearer now

Comment: @danielb yes I know that works

Comment: Yeah man, much :-) It's still a bit weird, again testing both work. I'd just forget abt it and simply `sudo visudo` any sudoers file I need to work with :-) I  hope someone In The Know can answer.

Comment: I would guess that it has something to do with permissions and the save algorithm. It might be that `nano` saves to a temporary file and then deletes and renames, while `vim` does overwrite. But I can't test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you are editing a file as root/superuser, if the write bit is not set for the file Vim will go into readonly mode, but you can still make changes (with a warning from Vim the first time you make a change), and you can still write the file if you force it using `:w!`.